# Adding query parms to WebTarget with Jersey Client 2.x

Tags: java-8, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm trying to add query params to WebTarget of Jax-RS(Jersey Client 2.x) as below

```
public WebTarget webTarget(String path, Map<String, String> queryMap) {

        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(this.address.getUrl()).path(path);
        if (queryMap != null)
            queryMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> webTarget.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        return webTarget;

}
```

*The issue is WebTarget is immutable* and returns new WebTarget every time `.queryParam()` is invoked, *but cannot use mutable variables inside the lambda expression to reassign the WebTarget* to be used within the `forEach()`, how do I capture the immutable WebTarget within each iteration of forEach() (dont want to loose out on the lambda expression conciseness!!!)

any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use:

```
public WebTarget webTarget(String path, Map<String, String> queryMap) {
    final WebTarget[] webTarget = {this.client.target(this.address.getUrl()).path(path)};
    if (queryMap != null)
        queryMap.forEach((key, value) -> webTarget[0] = webTarget[0].queryParam(key, value));

    return webTarget[0];
}
```

But I nevertheless think that it is better to use a for each.

```
public WebTarget webTarget(String path, Map<String, String> queryMap) {
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(this.address.getUrl()).path(path);
    if (queryMap != null)
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: queryMap.entrySet())
            webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return webTarget;
}
```

Comment: This approach is very good to have a generic api.